# 3D cylinder parameters from 7 points?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I would like to code a RANSAC algorithm for detecting cylinders in a 3D scene. I can manage with plane, spheres etc... but I struggle to understand how to extract parameters of a cylinder model from N points.

I went through the litterature and could find the paper "Direct Solutions for computing cylinders from minimal sets of 3D points" (Beder, Förstner, 2006), among others. But I don't really understand how to apply their method.

So, given 7 points, how do I compute the parameters of the unique cylinder of arbitrary orientation passing through those 7 points?

It should involve SVD / nullspace calculations but I'm a bit confused as to how to proceed. Can someone help?

Comment: If you can detect planes, could you try detecting two parallel circular planes?

Comment: This may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023842/cylinder-in-3d-from-five-points