# Simplified equation for 3D Cone? Want to recover cone from sea of points

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

While I see there are a number of responses out there for the equation for a cone, I'm looking for something just a little bit different.

I am trying to take a sea of points and recover the primitive shape that it originates from.  At present, I can use a linear equation solver and some simple algebra to recover a cylinder and a sphere (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023842/cylinder-in-3d-from-five-points) for the cylinder method), but I also want to be able to recover a cone.

At a general level, a cone could be described as a surface that is at a particular angle $\theta$ to an origin (C)-normal (N) vector pair:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(P-C) \cdot N}{||P-C||} = cos \; \theta
\end{equation}

Or, by doing some simplifications (such as assuming N is not unit length), this would turn into:

\begin{equation}
(P-C)\cdot N = ||P-C||
\end{equation}

And by expansion:
\begin{equation}
(P\cdot N - C\cdot N)^2 = (P-C) \cdot (P-C)
\end{equation}

Eventually, I could expand this out to its quadric form ($a\;x^2 + b\;xy + c\;xz + d\;x + ...+j=0$ with (a,b,c,...) represented by C and N.  But the expansion appears to be quite ridiculous at this point and I'm hoping I'm missing a trick to make it easier to recover some of the parameters.

The question I have is: if I can determine a, b, ..., j, what is the easiest way to recover C and N?  Or is there another representative cone equation I should use instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are going to want to fit spheres, cylinders, and cones, why not fit a general quadric $\mathbf p^T\mathbf A\mathbf p+\mathbf b^T\mathbf p+c=0$ and then check if it is nearly a sphere/cylinder/cone?

Comment: **That's what I'm doing**, just not in as pretty of form :).  But the coefficients for the cone appear to me to be quite complicated when you have a cone with nonzero origin and nonaxis direction.

Comment: Oh right, I see. Then if the quadric is a cone, the matrix $\mathbf A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-\lambda_3$, and the axis of the cone is along the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of opposite sign. However, you will still have to check that it is not a hyperboloid.

Comment: Correction: The matrix has two eigenvalues that are equal, and a third eigenvalue that is of the opposite sign (but not necessarily equal magnitude, unlike what I said in my previous comment).

Comment: Hey thanks for those facts about testing a quadric equation for a cone.  But what I'm after is to recover the focal point, axis of rotation, and dispersion angle (C,N,$\theta$) detailed above.  This isn't a one-off problem; I want to use these techniques to extract shapes (plane, cylinder, sphere, cone, torus) from 3D scenes with up to 2 million triangles arranged in different surfaces.